# Delete a vertex,how to show that graph remains connected?

Tags: graph-theory

How can I show that at each **connected graph(there is a path from any point to any other point in the graph)**,there is a vertex,so that if we delete this vertex and the edges that conclude to it,the graph remains connected?

Comment: May help to post a definition of a *coherent graph*, I don't think it's commonly known. I found one here on p.10: http://www.idsia.ch/~zaffalon/papers/2009aij-cgs.pdf (Def.9).

Comment: Is it possible that you mean connected rather than coherent?

Comment: Yes,I mean that the graph should be connected!!

Answer (score 8):

Since $G$ is connected, it has a spanning tree. Consider a leaf of this tree.

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood the question.+1

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following graph: It is connected, you can get from any vertex to any vertex. But what happens if you take away one vertex? Then it stops being connected.

[image]

In Graph theory there is something called the [connectivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_%28graph_theory%29) of a graph. It tells you how many vertices need to be deleted before it becomes disconnected. In this case it is one. Because taking out B makes it disconnected.

---

Let G be any graph. If G has a vertex with degree 1 take it away. See it is still connected.

Suppose G has no vertex of degree $1$ Then look at a [spanning tree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136249/how-to-show-that-every-connected-graph-has-a-spanning-tree-working-from-the-gra) of the graph. Then this tree will have a leaf(a vertex with degree 1) take it away and see the tree is still connected. So putting back the edges will not take away the connectivity of the graph.

Comment: If,for example,we take out $G$,will the graph be still connected?

Comment: Yes because you can still get from any vertex to any other vertex.

Comment: So,how can I show that at each connected graph,there is at least such a vertex,that can be deleted,so that then the graph is still connected?

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood your question. Casteels gives an answer to that. But it seems it doesn't satisfy you. Let me try to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be a connected graph with at least two vertices. Choose vertices $u,v\in V(G)$ so as to maximize the distance $d(u,v)$, the length of a shortest path from $u$ to $v$. If $w\in V(G)-\{v\}$, then a shortest path from $u$ to $w$ does not go through $v$; if it did, we would have $d(u,w)\gt d(u,v)$. Thus every vertex of $G-v$ is connected to $u$ by a path in $G-v$; i.e., the graph $G-v$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds incorrect to me. If this is true, let $G = (V, E)$ be such graph. Then, there is one vertex $v_1$, removing which from $G$ we get another coherent graph $G_1 = G - v_1$.

Applying the same principle, there exists some $v_2$ such that $G_2 = G_1 -v_2$ is coherent. By induction, it's easy to see that the empty graph is coherent.

That contradicts axiom (CG1) on p.10 in the above-cited [definition paper](http://www.idsia.ch/~zaffalon/papers/2009aij-cgs.pdf).